# Dropconnect implementation in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to code dropconnect for `Conv2D` and `TransposeConv2D` layer. Followed the tutorial in https://pytorchnlp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torchnlp/nn/weight_drop.html to create it.

```py
import torch
from torch.nn import Parameter

def _weight_drop(module, weights, dropout):
    for name_w in weights:
        w = getattr(module, name_w)
        del module._parameters[name_w]
        module.register_parameter(name_w + '_raw', Parameter(w))
    original_module_forward = module.forward

    def forward(*args, **kwargs):
        for name_w in weights:
            raw_w = getattr(module, name_w + '_raw')
            w = torch.nn.functional.dropout(raw_w, p=dropout, training=module.training)
            setattr(module, name_w, w)
        return original_module_forward(*args, **kwargs)
    setattr(module, 'forward', forward)
        
class WeightDropConv2d(torch.nn.Conv2d):
    def __init__(self, *args, weight_dropout=0.0, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        weights = ['weight']
        _weight_drop(self, weights, weight_dropout)
        
class WeightDropConvTranspose2d(torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d):
    def __init__(self, *args, weight_dropout=0.0, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        weights = ['weight']
        _weight_drop(self, weights, weight_dropout)
```

The versions of Torch and Cuda I use:

- `torch.version.cuda`: 1.1.0
- `torch.__version__`: 9.0.176

I get the following error in the 2nd epoch:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropconnect.py", line 110, in <module>
    out = model(image)
  File "/home/sbhand2s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "dropconnect.py", line 73, in forward
    out = self.c1(x)
  File "/home/sbhand2s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "dropconnect.py", line 34, in forward
    setattr(module, name_w, w)
  File "/home/sbhand2s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 558, in __setattr__
    .format(torch.typename(value), name))
TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.cuda.FloatTensor' as parameter 'weight' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)
```

This error occurs in the second epoch when I switch from `.eval()` to `.train()`. This error does not occur if I don't call `.eval()`

Any suggestions on why this error is occurring or how to implement dropconnect in a better manner?

Code to replicate issue:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
import torch
from torch import nn

layers = []
layers.append(("conv_1", WeightDropConv2d(1,3,3,1,1,weight_dropout=0.5)))
layers.append(("conv_2", WeightDropConv2d(3,3,3,1,1,weight_dropout=0.5)))
layers.append(("conv_3", WeightDropConv2d(3,1,3,1,1,weight_dropout=0.5)))

model = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict(layers))

pred = model(torch.randn([1,1,3,3]))

model.eval()
pred = model(torch.randn([1,1,3,3]))

model.train()
pred = model(torch.randn([1,1,3,3]))
```

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite get that method to work either (had a different error though), but here's a simpler method that seems to be working:

```
for i in range(num_batches):

    orig_params = []
    for n, p in model.named_parameters():
        orig_params.append(p.clone())
        p.copy_(F.dropout(p.data, p=drop_prob) * (1 - drop_prob))

    output = model(input)
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(output, label)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()

    for orig_p, (n, p) in zip(orig_params, model.named_parameters()):  
        p.copy_(orig_p)

    optimizer.step()
```

(tested in Pytorch 1.4)

Answer (score 0):

After hitting similar roadblocks I read this article: https://tomaxent.com/2018/01/15/DropConnect-Implementation-in-Python-and-TensorFlow-Repost/ . It stated out that the only difference between Dropout and DropConnect implementational is, that is whether or not the weights in the masked matrix get scaled up (to preserve the expected sum). Although the article talks about Tensorflow it can also be applied to PyTorch, in my opinion. So DropConnect could look like this in PyTorch:

```py
self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(p=self.p)
...
def forward(self, x):
...
  x = self.dropout (x) * (1-self.p)
```

Answer (score 0):

by the implements of drop_connect in efficientnet from efficient-pytorch:

```py
def drop_connect(inputs, p, training):
    """Drop connect.

    Args:
        input (tensor: BCWH): Input of this structure.
        p (float: 0.0~1.0): Probability of drop connection.
        training (bool): The running mode.

    Returns:
        output: Output after drop connection.
    """
    assert p >= 0 and p <= 1, 'p must be in range of [0,1]'

    if not training:
        return inputs

    batch_size = inputs.shape[0]
    keep_prob = 1 - p

    # generate binary_tensor mask according to probability (p for 0, 1-p for 1)
    random_tensor = keep_prob
    random_tensor += torch.rand([batch_size, 1, 1, 1], dtype=inputs.dtype, device=inputs.device)
    binary_tensor = torch.floor(random_tensor)

    output = inputs / keep_prob * binary_tensor
    return output
```

I think it is more like as `x = self.dropout(x)/(1-self.p)`, since `output = inputs / keep_prob * binary_tensor` is equal to `output = (inputs * binary_tenosr) / (1 - self.p)`
the codes means random set 0 and then scale up remains.